# Why doesn't tty7 show a prompt with no display manager?

Tags: xorg, tty, display-manager

When I drop to tty1-tty6 through Ctrl-Alt-F[1-6] it shows a prompt, for obvious reasons (it's supposed to).

However, if I kill my display server, and thus X, through something like

```
sudo service gdm stop
```

tty7 is just blank. From my understanding X is started with `startx`, so I'm wondering why tty7 doesn't drop back to a prompt when X terminates.

Note: my knowledge of X and display servers is relatively limited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know this is all just tradition. "tty" is just a historical hangover from mainframes. 1-6 exist as login prompts because that's how they're defined in `/etc/default/console-setup` (and executed by `/etc/init/console-setup.conf`). This is *how* those TTYs get their login prompts and by extension, why tty7 does not have one.

But why 6 text ttys? And why tty7 for graphics? I have no idea.