# How do I use my second X server instance?

Tags: display, xserver, xinit

My main display is 0, running on terminal tty7, started automatically at boot time.

I switch to terminal tty2, start another X server as display 1 (`xinit -- :1`).

I can run programs from the X terminal and they are shown on display 1 (in tty2) ... so far so good.

Problem is, display 0 on tty7 is persistent (I can switch in and out of tty7 and my desktop is always there) but when I switch out of tty2 and back again, display 1 has stopped, just the normal black console.

Is it possible for me to make display 1 persistent so I can switch in and out of it ?

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with Xfce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display `:1` is running on "TTY8".

It's not actually a TTY, but <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> will get you there.

Comment: So it is ! Thanks for pointing that out. I was switching to tty2 to start the new X server, thats probably why I thought the display was on tty2. I now just start the new X server from a terminal on my desktop, and sure enough it is started on (not tty)8.  Thanks !

Comment: On a side note, and just for my own learning, why is it displayed on 8 ? Is it possible for me to display it on 1 or 2 or 3 or whatever ?

Comment: I don't know why but [I think I know how](http://askubuntu.com/a/310811/449). It's just incrementing up based on what's already taken by TTYs.

Comment: I read the link, thanks. Well, I know a little more today than I knew yesterday. Cheers :)